# VARIADIC MACRO compile error

Tags: c++

I want to learn how to use macro.

I simply write a sample but failed to compile on my local g++4.9

```
#define P(...) printf("13", ##__VA_ARGS__)
int main() {
// your code goes here
P();
return 0;
}
```

I will get compile error as below

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:4:42: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
 #define P(...) printf("13", ##__VA_ARGS__)
                                          ^
main.cpp:7:5: note: in expansion of macro 'P'
     P();
     ^
```

But the same code can be compiled on ideone....
http://ideone.com/ucEXXz

and also by VS2015.

Is there any reasonable explanation for this?

How can I write a portable macro for all compiler....

Thanks.

Comment: the code is not the same - on coliru stdio.h is not included - iostream is...

Answer (score 1):

In C, functions that take variable arguments require a prototype declaration, while in C++, all functions require a prototype. The declaration for `printf` can be found in `stdio.h`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define P(...) printf("13", ##__VA_ARGS__)
int main() {
P();
return 0;
}
```

The `##__VA_ARGS__` syntax is non-standard. It is a "swallow comma if the `__VA_ARGS__` is empty" extension implemented by GCC, and seems to have been adopted by other compilers.

Regarding the behavior of `-std=c++14`:

> The compiler can accept several base standards, such as ‘c90’ or ‘c++98’, and GNU dialects of those standards, such as ‘gnu90’ or ‘gnu++98’. When a base standard is specified, the compiler accepts all programs following that standard plus those using GNU extensions that do not contradict it. For example, -std=c90 turns off certain features of GCC that are incompatible with ISO C90, such as the asm and typeof keywords, but not other GNU extensions that do not have a meaning in ISO C90, such as omitting the middle term of a ?: expression.
>   
>   <sub>[GCC documentation for `-std=`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html)</sub>

The `##__VA_ARGS__` extension does not conflict with the standard. What is causing it to be rejected by the coliru site is that the `-pedantic` flag is set.

> Valid ISO C and ISO C++ programs should compile properly with or without this option (though a rare few require -ansi or a -std option specifying the required version of ISO C). However, without this option, certain GNU extensions and traditional C and C++ features are supported as well. With this option, they are rejected.
>   <sub>[GCC documentation for `-pedantic`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options)</sub>

Comment: but passing ```-std=c++14``` or any standard will remove this extension even in gcc and thats why the coliru example does not compile

Comment: @onqtam: That is not what `-std` does. See my update.

Comment: Use -std=gnu++11 to re-enable GNU extensions.

Comment: Briefly, it seems there is no way to write a portable c++ code with variadic macro?

Comment: I need to use -std=c++14 or 11 since I used some variadic template.
I will try to use -std=gnu++11 for workaround